# How to do classification on metadata tags?

Tags: java

I have some metadata file `sample.json`. Now i want to classify my metadata file using java.

This is my metadata file:

```
{"Author: ":null,"Title: ":" Syllabus","File name: ":" Syllabus Exp.htm"}
{"Author: ":null,"Title: ":" sample Syllabus","File name: ":" Syllabus.htm"}
{"Author: ":null,"Title: ":null,"File name: ":"sample.pdf"}.
```

please suggest me how to classify above metadata file.

thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? put items into different groups based on their title?

Comment: 1) What do you mean by classify? 2) What have you already tried?

Comment: Start with: "Machine Learning: Classification"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [JSon parser](http://json.org/java/) to convert your "metadata" lines into Java objects which you can add to collections and do whatever your want with (filter, sort, etc).